# entity not defined in xml file

Tags: xml, cdata

I am creating my feed dynamically. Using  etc tags. In title or description whenever there is ’ it gives error "Entity 'rsquo' not defined". Is there any way to replace ’ or parse it. 
I tried to make entity in xml file, when wrote code for making entity, this result This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
I tried to make entity in this way

I am new to write feed. Please provide any guideline. Thanks

Comment: It sounds like you are slapping raw HTML into the XML. Don't do that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [php output xml produces parse error "&rsquo;"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3142543/php-output-xml-produces-parse-error-rsquo)