# Problems came up in the following areas during load: Table

Tags: excel, temporary-files

I have generated an excel file from xml. But i can not open it with Excel. Excel gives the following error opening it:

```
Problems came up in the following areas during load: 
Table
```

Then it shows a message that the log file corresponding the error can be found at : `C:/Documents and Setting/myUserName/Local Settings/Temporary Internet Files/Content.MSO/xxxxx.log`

But i can not find Content.MSO folder in my windows. I checked folder settings and made all folders visible but i still can not access this folder. So that i can not analise the log file.
how could i find the generated log file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem without analising the log file. i stil can not access the log file in temporary internet files. But i realised that i put a string(non-number) characters on a number-styled cell in Excel xml. So if you having the similar issues about your Excel file generated from xml, then have a look at if your cell values are appopriate with your cell data type.

Comment: Thanks for this. I had space characters in front of a couple numbers and that caused this error.

Comment: In my case I had the same error as the OP but the cause was missing `ss:Type` attributes in the Data tags, eg. `ss:Type="String"`

Answer (score 3):

If you type or paste the path of the log file into Explorer or your text editor of choice, you may find that the folder does exist, despite being invisible.

Comment: I found the same thing (despite all files folders visible, this folder still wasn't until manually typed into the explorer bar). Unfortunately for me the log file was useless ("HTML error in cell value : ND"), and the file is large.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was a `<Row>` with an incorrect ss:Index

I was using a template and the last row had a fixed Index=100. If the number of rows I added exceeded 100, this last row had a wrong index and excel threw the error without any other message or log (MacOSX, Excel 15.25.1). I wish they printed more informative error messages, what a waste of our time.

Answer (score 1):

Excel 2016. My error message was "Worksheet Settings". Path was pointing to non-existing file.

My cause of the problem was ExpandedRowCount not big enough for number of rows in Worksheet. If you add rows in XML directly (i.e. on a machine where Excel is not installed), make sure to increment number of rows in ExpandedRowCount.

Answer (score 0):

yes.Even i too faced the same problem and problem was with the data type of cells ofexcel generated using xslt

Answer (score 0):

In addition to checking the data being used vs "Type" assigned, make sure that the list of characters that need to be encoded for XML are indeed encoded.

I had a system that appeared to be working, but then some user data including `&` and `<` was throwing this error.

If you're not sure what's going on with your file, try http://www.xmlvalidation.com/ - that helped be spot the issue in a large file immediately.

I used this function to fix it, [modified from this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9446666/947370):

```
function xmlsafe($s) {
  return str_replace(array('&','>','<','"'), array('&amp;','&gt;','&lt;','&quot;'), $s);
}
```

and then run `echo xmlsafe($myvalue)` where you were just echoing `$myvalue` in your script.

This seems to be more appropriate for XML than `htmlentities()` or other options built into PHP.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, and the answer was - type of Cell was Number and some values doesn't converts to this type on my backend.

Answer (score -1):

I had the **SAME** problem,
and its because de file is **TOO BIG**.
I try an extract from SAP, more little than the one with that make the error)  and save it in XML file. and it WORK, no more error.

so maybe if you can save in 2 Excel files XML instead of 1 it will be good ;)

ALicia